# Recursively adding values to own parent in a recursive List<T>

Tags: c#, list, recursion

I have two CSV files which I merge together, create a recursive list, then use that data as the source for a *TreeView*.

The first file has three fields [*Id; Level; Description*] and looks like this:

[image]

The second file has three fields [*Id; Description; Wage*] and looks like this:

[image]

Before merging the *TreeView* Looks like this:

[image]

The colors are there to make it easier to understand what is being displayed.

- Red: This is the Id of the item.
- Gray: This is the parent Id (not provided in the source file so I had to create that myself based on each items level).
- Black: This is the description.
- Green: This is the Default value which is *0,00* as nothing has been inserted yet.

What I'm doing is inserting the data of the second file, using the provided Id as the *insertion id* so I know where to insert the item, accumulating the values for that item and displaying that accumulated value in the items own row. This is what it looks like after merging the data:

[image]

As you can see, the three items have been inserted at the correct position and the parent of the inserted items has the accumulated value (e.g. Id *1121* displays *200,00*, Id *1123* displays *100,00*) but it is not complete, as I need the values to be accumulated all the way **up** the *TreeView*!

This is what I'm hoping to achieve (some values have been hard-coded);

[image]

I'm guessing that after inserting the items at any given position and accumulating the totals for that parent, I need to go up the tree, adding the parents total to each of its parents until I get to the root item - I simply have no idea as how to accomplish this!

I hope that you gurus can see that I have put a little effort into this and have a little time to help me. Your time is, as always, very much appreciated.

Have a great day!

**EDIT**

Thank you all for pointing out that I should actually show some code and not only what I have accomplished until now - sorry for that!

Here is where I'm merging the data:

*IndentedData* is the TreeView's data source.

*MergedData* is the data contained in the second file.

As suggested by Peter Duniho, here is the actual code and not a screenshot.

```
/*
 * Merge the data
*/
TransformedData target = null;
MergeData mergeData = null;

var groupedMergedData = this.MergedData.GroupBy(x => x.Position).ToList();

foreach (var group in groupedMergedData)
{
   var groupTarget = group.FirstOrDefault();

   if (groupTarget != null)
   {
      target = this.IndentedData.FirstOrDefaultFromMany(x => x.Children, x => x.Id == groupTarget.Position);

      if (target != null)
      {
         double d = 0;

         for (int i = 0; i < group.Count(); i++)
         {
            mergeData = group.ElementAt(i);

            double.TryParse(mergeData.YearCurrent, out d);

            target.Children.Insert(i, new TransformedData()
            {
               Id = mergeData.Account,
               Description = string.Format("{0} {1}", mergeData.Account, mergeData.Description),
               CurrentYear = d
            });

            target.CurrentYear += d;
         }
      }
   }
}
```

As suggested by Servy, here are what the two classes look like:

```
public class MergeData
{
    public string Position { get; set; }
    public string Account { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string YearCurrent { get; set; }
}

public class TransformedData
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string ParentId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public double CurrentYear { get; set; }
    public List<TransformedData> Children { get; set; }

    public TransformedData()
    {
        this.Children = new List<TransformedData>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show us your actual code?

Comment: Can you please post the code that you are using.  The screenshots are helpful, but they won't help us figure out what's wrong.

Comment: If the tree construction is fine you don't need to show it to us, but we'll need to see what the items in the tree look like in order to know how to extend them to support this functionality.

Comment: Given the complete lack of commas in your example data, in what way should we consider that data `CSV` as you've stated? This looks more like just a custom text format.

Comment: Please post _actual code_, not some screenshot of code. Please provide [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that clearly illustrates the problem. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for advice on how to present your question in a clear, answerable way.

Comment: @Aybe - Yes I am using WPF

Comment: @PeterDuniho - I'm dealing with data created in Germany where it is common to refer to the _C_ in CSV as a character-separated value, not a comma. Here, the comma is used for decimal places and is therefore not widely used as a separator. Sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the sum of the value for not only the item itself, but also all of it's children, just add a property that adds the current items value to the computed value of all of its children:

```
public class TransformedData
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string ParentId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public double CurrentYear { get; set; }
    public double RenameThisProperty
    {
        get
        {
            return CurrentYear + Children.Sum(child => child.RenameThisProperty);
        }
    }
    public List<TransformedData> Children { get; set; }

    public TransformedData()
    {
        this.Children = new List<TransformedData>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Servy, thank you for your suggestion.I am waiting for a Train right now and am viewing this on my phone - can you explain the _Sum_ for me a Little? Do I need an Extension method or what do you mean exactly? Thank you.

Comment: @user3235445 It's the LINQ Sum method.

Comment: thank you for the explanation - I will look at it tomorrow morning.

Comment: Hello Servy, your answer was brilliant! I had to remove the line:

     `target.CurrentYear += d;`

as, thanks to your changes in the class, this was no longer required.

I really thought that I would have to traverse back up the tree, I never would have come up with your solution, thank you very much for opening my eyes there.